# How to get data using Geomesa

Tags: java, geolocation, geocoding, geomesa

Is there any way we can get intersection of States and Counties using Geomesa-Accumulo from a large Dataset using queries (CQL,JAVA) and reverse geocoding ?

Comment: Are you trying to do reverse geocoding for a large number of points?

Comment: One option would be to use Spark + GeoMesa to do a broadcast join: https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/tutorials/broadcast-join.html.

Comment: Yes, i want to use lang/lat to get states or counties i used java to query my Database but it's getting hard when entries passed 1 Billion

Comment: What do you mean by 'getting hard'?  Is your database slowing down?  If so, what size is your Accumulo cluster?

Query performance is going to be impacted by cluster size, data distribution, indexes created and the queries you run.

Comment: The queries i run are through Java hence the slowing down but the i'm using 3 servers Geomesa-hadoop-Accumulo the Details of the DFS used :65.98 GB (1.28%) remaining: 4.68 TB (92.84%)